# Blender new versions don't work well on AMD Radeon HD 7570M

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Blender new versions don't work well on my device
Is  video card AMD Radeon HD 7570M working for new blender version anymore ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AMD Radeon HD 7570M is from the [AMD Radeon 7000M series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_HD_7000M_series) and has the old TeraScale 2 micro-architecture. The [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x and 2.9x state that [GCN first generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Features_Overview) is required for running Blender.

> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> - **NVIDIA**: GeForce 400 and newer, Quadro Tesla GPU architecture and newer, including RTX-based cards, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all [GeForce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce#GeForce_400_series_and_500_series) and [Quadro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadro#Quadro_FX_(with_CUDA_and_OpenCL,_but_no_Vulkan)) GPUs)
> - **AMD**: **GCN 1st gen and newer** ([list of all AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units))
> - **Intel**: Haswell and newer ([list of all Intel GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units))
> - **macOS**: version 10.13 or newer with supported hardware

Unfortunately, this means that your GPU is below the minimum requirements and Blender developers don't provide support for it. Graphics glitches and even crashes due to unpatched bugs in the graphics driver can occur on unsupported hardware. You may have to use a [previous release of Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/) with lower requirements.