# Blender not opening on old pc with Window 10 (64)

Tags: opengl

When I try to open the blender, it gives this warning:
[image]

However, in the scan I see that there is the latest version of open GL installed:

Will there be any way to fix the issue and get blender working?

[image]

Comment: Old computer usually do not support the needed version of OpenGL and even if it does, OpenGL features might not be supported.
Using old Blender versions might work.

Comment: Okies, and there are no methods to check compatibility test?

Comment: I would install the OpenGL Extension viewer.
http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.html
To make sure you have at least OpenGL 3.3 support.

Comment: I already installed that software and also posted its results. it says Version 4.5 is present on the machine.

Comment: Please see this thread: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200346/blender-new-versions-dont-work-well-on-amd-radeon-hd-7570m